# Strict concavity with respect to one argument of a concave homogeneous function?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, homogeneous-equation

Let $f(x,y)$ be a concave, strictly increasing function that is also homogenous of degree one. Is it true that $f$ is strictly concave with respect to one of its arguments? I.e. do we have
$$
f(x,ay+(1-a)y')>af(x,y)+(1-a)f(x,y')
$$
For instance, this is true in the case $f(x,y)=x^by^{1-b}$ with $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$ and $0< b< 1$. Is that result more general?

Comment: If $f$ is (strictly) concave it is surely (strictly) concave with respect to each argument. Just set $x=x'$  in $f(ax+(1-a)x',ay+(1-a)y')>af(x,y)+(1-a)f(x',y')$.

Comment: @MartinR $f$ is not strictly concave. Just concave.

Comment: How about $f(x,y)=x+y$?

Comment: @N.Quy What about it?

Comment: It’s concave, strictly increasing, homogenous of degree 1 but not strictly concave wrt to one of its argument. So I think in general your statement is not true.

Comment: @N.Quy Got it, thanks!